# Microsoft Graph API - "GraphOrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound" error code

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

My problem is exactly like here, word to word:

[Microsoft Graph Api /calendar endpoint returns "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound", but /users endpoint works without problems. How to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347728/microsoft-graph-api-calendar-endpoint-returns-organizationfromtenantguidnotfou)

I got Office 365 development subscription, created new Azure AD with a new application, but still no luck. I can view a list of users through API, but when I try to see specific user's calendar, or mail list I see this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
        "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '<my tenant id is here>' does not exist.",
    }
}
```

**Edit: Ok, so I waited a bit and the problem is resolved now. I did not make any changes, tried making a request again and the error is now gone. It looks like Azure AD needed some time to setup.**

Answer (score 0):

The new Azure AD you created does not have Office 365.
Thus it cannot have calendars.
/users works because that is an Azure AD endpoint.

If you want to access calendars for your development O365 tenant, register the app in your O365 AAD tenant that you got when you created the development tenant.

Comment: It does have Office 365. I can see it on "Azure Active Directory" interface,it says "Azure AD for Office 365" just below the name of the directory. But actually the issue is resolved now, please check my edit above.

Comment: Ah :) That's good to hear! I must have misunderstood when you said you created an AAD, since one is created for you typically. That is certainly the correct AAD.