# Azure AD token calling MS Graph Api for getting email messages - Got 401 unauthorized

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, http-status-code-401

I have been struggling with this problem for 2 days.

I am currently trying to build a web application which is able to revoke the MS Graph Api to fetch the current user's email messages.

Firstly I have register an AD and a application within it, and follow the instructions setup the permissions.

Now I have achieved obtaining the **access token** by utilising the ADAL.js library. The access token is in the jwt format, and when I check it via jwt.ms, it seems like have all the permissions I need:

```
"scp": "Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite profile User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All"
```

And then when I tried to used the access token to call the graph api:

```
GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
```

It worked and return my profile details.

But when I used the token to call:
GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/"

It returns 401 Unauthorised error:

```
code: "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound"
message: "The tenant for tenant guid <my tenant id> does not exist.
```

I tried using both the JavaScript Fetch and also PostMan to try the api, same error returned.

Can anybody give a hand on this, I will very much appreciate it!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was caused by the tenant and the account. When you request the graph api, the `me` in your api may represent the account which is not in your AD or is a personal account. **You need a Microsoft office 365 account with subscription**. Here are two posts([post1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24064) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347728/calendar-endpoint-returns-organizationfromtenantguidnotfound)) which related to your issue for your reference.

You need to check the account and the application, if still can't solve the issue, I think you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).