# Fetch microsoft outlook calendar events using graph api in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, outlook-graph-api

I am trying to create the simplest calendar application that can show users calendar events for microsoft outlook users.

I am using [@azure/msal-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node) for authentication.
I am using [`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to fetch events

I am able to authenticate and get a token but getting error in graph api request.

Here is my code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { PublicClientApplication, LogLevel } = require('@azure/msal-node');

// Initialize the MSAL client with your authentication configuration
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}`,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
        console.log(message);
      },
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
      logLevel: LogLevel.Info
    }
  }
};

const msalClient = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

// Create an Express app
const app = express();

// Define a route for initiating the login process
app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const authCodeUrlParameters = {
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access', 'Calendars.Read'],
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
  };

  // Generate the authorization URL
  const authUrl = await msalClient.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters);
  console.log('alok', authUrl)

  // Redirect the user to the authorization URL
  res.redirect(authUrl);
});

// Define a route for handling the redirect callback
app.get('/redirect', async (req, res) => {
  const tokenRequest = {
    code: req.query.code,
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access', 'Calendars.Read'],
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
  };

  try {
    // Acquire an access token using the authorization code
    const response = await msalClient.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest);

    const token = response.accessToken;
    const graphEndpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events';
    const resp = await fetch(graphEndpoint, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.log('Calendar events:', data);
    res.send('Calendar events' + JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle the token acquisition error
    console.log(error);
    res.send('Authentication failed.');
  }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

I am getting response on graph api call

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid 'd19680c7-8d06-4906-92bd-0e4c1b318f03' does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "oAuthEventOperationId": "213fd067-58a7-420a-bd93-64b4f68e6cae",
      "oAuthEventcV": "M17KB0OaSeGkiZmrisUKhA.1.1.1",
      "errorUrl": "https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant",
      "requestId": "aee1392f-5824-432c-82ef-9083be5001af",
      "date": "2023-05-22T11:07:23"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to get help from [Calendar endpoint returns OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347728/calendar-endpoint-returns-organizationfromtenantguidnotfound) but still getting same error.

My `clientId`, `clientSecret` and `authority` are correct thats why I am able to get token.
What I am missing so getting error in graph api call?

Comment: Could you decode the access token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and check `scp` and `tid` claims?

Comment: Also check whether `d19680c7-8d06-4906-92bd-0e4c1b318f03` from error is your **tenant ID** or not where your application is registered?

Comment: Are you using personal Microsoft account or local Azure AD account(ends with .onmicrosoft.com) to sign-in?

Comment: @Sridevi: I am ussing personal microsoft account whose user name is my email address e.g. `something@gmail.com`

Comment: Did you assign Office 365 license to that user?

Comment: @Sridevi: I am able to use https://www.office.com/ using same account. I am able to create calendar evets using same `something@gmail.com`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253779/discussion-between-sridevi-and-alok).

Comment: I have shared link with code in chat.

Comment: Could you try changing the **authority URL** to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/` as you are using personal Microsoft account?

Comment: yes with ending slash its same error.

Comment: Could you include [Overview](https://i.imgur.com/BLKVOrb.png) snapshot to know how you registered your application?

Comment: Have you created app registration in Azure AD **B2C** tenant by selecting **Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory** (user flows) as account type?

Comment: @Sridevi: my problem is solved by answer given in this question. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your conversation with @Sridevi, you have registered your application in Azure AD B2C tenant.
To begin, it's important to note that Azure AD B2C is distinct from Azure AD. Unlike Azure AD, which caters to organizational users, Azure AD B2C is specifically designed for consumer applications, targeting non-organizational users or consumers.

Based on the configuration details you provided, the endpoint you're attempting to use in your application corresponds to Azure AD rather than Azure AD B2C.

In your application, you are trying to retrieve a token using the Azure AD endpoint but encountering an error ("OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound") because of a mismatch between the tenants. The application is registered in the Azure AD B2C tenant, which might be causing the issue when interacting with the Azure AD endpoint.

To resolve your issue,
You need to register your application in Azure AD with supported account types

[image]

and set https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/ in authority

However, If you have only users with Personal Microsoft Accounts, then select last option while registering the application
[image]
and set https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/ in the authority URL to get valid access token.

Note: Access token for personal Microsoft accounts can't be decoded due to security reasons. You can only able to decode id_token using jwt.ms for personal accounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for so accuarate and elaborate answer :)

Comment: Can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/76525504/1762051