# Receiving extra updated change notification through webhook on creation and deletion of outlook event

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, outlook-graph-api

I want to receive change notification on create, update and delete of outlook events. I created a subscription by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=http

```js
var options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json", Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "notificationUrl": "https://somehost.com/notification",
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "https://somehost.com/notification",
    "resource": "/me/events",
    "expirationDateTime": new Date(Date.now() + 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000).toISOString(),
    "clientState": "alok"
  })
}
const response = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions', options)
const responseData = await response.json()
console.log(responseData)
```

I am receiving notifications but I am receiving extra notifications also in case of creation and deletion of outlook events.

| Change Type | Expected Notification | Received Notifications |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event Creation | created | 1. Created 2. Updated |
| Event Updation | updated | 1. updated |
| Event Deletion | deleted | 1. deleted 2. updated |

In case of creation and deletion I am reciving extra `updated` notification

Here is example of notifcations on creation of a event.

```js
{
  subscriptionId: '73c4bcce-e71e-47c7-8400-e460084312c5',
  subscriptionExpirationDateTime: '2023-06-24T06:04:42.698+00:00',
  changeType: 'created',
  resource: 'Users/e5d15677d1fc5621/Events/AQMkADAwATY0MDABLWEwNzcALTM2NWMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADIxlJtpcRgkeTMxwbsaPXdwcAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAAAgENAAAAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAGBgAKcsIAAAA=',
  resourceData: {
    '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.Graph.Event',
    '@odata.id': 'Users/e5d15677d1fc5621/Events/AQMkADAwATY0MDABLWEwNzcALTM2NWMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADIxlJtpcRgkeTMxwbsaPXdwcAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAAAgENAAAAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAGBgAKcsIAAAA=',
    '@odata.etag': 'W/"DwAAABYAAAA5FmSNVUErTJvOlV6WEEv3AAYGEoWX"',
    id: 'AQMkADAwATY0MDABLWEwNzcALTM2NWMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADIxlJtpcRgkeTMxwbsaPXdwcAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAAAgENAAAAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAGBgAKcsIAAAA='
  },
  clientState: 'alok',
  tenantId: ''
}

{
  subscriptionId: '73c4bcce-e71e-47c7-8400-e460084312c5',
  subscriptionExpirationDateTime: '2023-06-24T06:04:42.698+00:00',
  changeType: 'updated',
  resource: 'Users/e5d15677d1fc5621/Events/AQMkADAwATY0MDABLWEwNzcALTM2NWMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADIxlJtpcRgkeTMxwbsaPXdwcAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAAAgENAAAAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAGBgAKcsIAAAA=',
  resourceData: {
    '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.Graph.Event',
    '@odata.id': 'Users/e5d15677d1fc5621/Events/AQMkADAwATY0MDABLWEwNzcALTM2NWMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADIxlJtpcRgkeTMxwbsaPXdwcAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAAAgENAAAAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAGBgAKcsIAAAA=',
    '@odata.etag': 'W/"DwAAABYAAAA5FmSNVUErTJvOlV6WEEv3AAYGEoWZ"',
    id: 'AQMkADAwATY0MDABLWEwNzcALTM2NWMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADIxlJtpcRgkeTMxwbsaPXdwcAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAAAgENAAAAORZkjVVBK0ybzpVelhBL9wAGBgAKcsIAAAA='
  },
  clientState: 'alok',
  tenantId: ''
}
```

How can I get rid of extra `updated` notification?